# delete unknown characters from my form data?

Tags: php

I want function

Delete all this characters from my forms

```
!@#$%^&*()-_+~`'";\|][/.,~
```

Only accept English characters linke (abcdefgh ....)

to use it in my registration form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = "something$^£^£$&£";
$text= preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $text);
echo $text; // output something
```

Comment: Thank you very very much ,, it's working fine but want also delete underscore _

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at inbuilt PHP functions :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use :[jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

It's powerful